# Modify one observable based on another

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on an application that has a favorites section. I'm pulling two sources of data one from a const file that I'm exporting as an observer(observerA$) and one from a database that contains only ids that have been favorited(observerB$), both work as intended. I would like to use the saved ids from observerB$ to mark a boolean in observerA$

ObserverA$ contains all info I'm using to populate the UI.
The interface for observerA

```
{
    title: string,
    id: number,
    page: string,
    subcategory: string,
    favorite?: boolean
}
```

observerB$ contains the IDs for items that are favorited
The interface for observerB$

```
{
   (some unrelated fields)
   id: number
}
```

I have it working by modifying an array inside of my component, but since this is being used in multiple components I would to subscribe observerA$ using asyncpipe to get updates without having to use a typescript array

Comment: Can you create a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) ?

Comment: We'd need a little more to go on because how you work with two arrays depends on the specifics of what you are trying to achieve. If you want some general ideas of working with a declarative approach, check out the first 30 min of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSsch65n8Yw

Comment: If ObserverA$ contains all info I'm using to populate the UI, then it looks like you only show one title? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, and sorry for the lack of information, I'm new to angular after working in knockoutjs for the past 3 years so I'm unsure of all the terminology. Essentially ObserverA$ contains all of the necessary info for the UI. I want to subscribe to that observer to populate the UI, but I need to modify the "favorite" boolean by matching IDs from observerB$. I'll look into using stackblitz for more info. I'm currently trying to use .map to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to compose an observable from two observable sources.  Let's call your two source observables `item$` and `favoriteIds$` for simplicity.

You can define your composed observable (*call it `itemWithFavoriteProperty$` just to be verbose*) like this:

```js
const itemWithFavoriteProperty$ = item$.pipe(
  switchMap(item => favoriteIds$.pipe(
    map(favoriteIds => favoriteIds.some(id => id === item.id)),
    map(favorite => ({...item, favorite}))
  ))
);
```

If you aren't familiar with [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), it basically subscribes to an observable source and emits its emissions.  So, whenever `item$` emits, `switchMap` will subscribe to `favoriteIds$` and emit the array of ids (*any time it changes*), which we then map:

- first to a boolean indicating if the item is in the favorite array
- then to a copy of the emitted `item` with the `favorite` property appended.

So `itemWithFavoriteProperty$` will emit any time `item$` emits, or whenever `favoriteIds$` emits.  However, we actually don't want to emit if the `favorite` boolean hasn't changed, so we can use [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged):

```js
const itemWithFavoriteProperty$ = item$.pipe(
  switchMap(item => favoriteIds$.pipe(
    map(favoriteIds => favoriteIds.some(id => id === item.id)),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    map(favorite => ({...item, favorite}))
  ))
);
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68669598?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) you can play around with.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It looks like this is the correct direction for me to go, I really appreciate it. The only issue I'm running into right now is that the I'm getting an error after the .some, it says that id does not exist on item[] so I think I have to unpack that array before it'll work, but this is a ton of help